# db:reset fails with "no such file or directory"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am upgrading a small app from Rails 3.0.9 to 3.2.6 and I getting an error running rake db:reset.  I have my seed data in .csv files that worked under 3.0.9.  When I run db:reset, it fails looking for a .yml file;

```
No such file or directory - db/seed/user.yml
```

I have a user.csv but no .yml files in the seed directory.  Anyone know why it would be looking for a .yml file?  Is .yml the default now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case it will help someone else, .csv is no longer supported in Rails 3.2, only .yml.